# SSL mode is set to ‘preferred’ and connection to remote is not using SSL

Tags: mongodb, ssl, mongo-shell

I have cluster of 3 shards servers, 3 Config servers and 1 mongos server in dev environment. I would like to make communication between Mongo components TLS compulsory and communication between applications and mongos as non-TLS. So, I am enabling **requireTLS** mode in shards and config only and I am enabling **preferTLS** mode in mongos server, so applications communicating to mongos will not require any TLS certs to provide. I have enabled the settings and cluster is running fine currently in dev. But I am getting one log message in mongos log, what does this mean? Is this technically right , requireTLS(mongod) + preferTLS(mongos)?

**Log**

> SSL mode is set to ‘preferred’ and connection to remote is not using
> SSL

Comment: `preferTLS` enables TLS for cluster internal communication. For cluster internal communication it makes no difference whether you use `preferTLS` or `requireTLS`.

Comment: Which connection is it? (should be written in the log message after or before) How does your `net` config look like (i.e. the certificate files)?

Comment: Why do you want to skip TLS on normal client connections?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I want to use preferTLS at Mongos side, this means mongos will accept non-tls connections from our internal apps, because we dont want to change the apps config files and provide the certs there. But we are using requireSSL at servers side which is our mogno shards and mongo config servers, here we need to provide the certs. just to clarify, apps(non-tls) -> mongos(preferTLS, expects tls,accepts both)->Mongod(requireTLS, accepts only TLS)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I am using lets encrypt in dev env, so I am not using CAFile in dev and QA, but we were using CAFile in prod as we are using entrust. But surprisingly, in prod mongos, I had faced one issue where commenting out the CA file helped us to remove those error logs from mongos.log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at my MongoDB, log says:

```
{
   "t": { "$date": "2024-02-14T11:57:37.397+01:00" },
   "s": "I",
   "c": "NETWORK",
   "id": 23838,
   "ctx": "conn69",
   "msg": "SSL mode is set to 'preferred' and connection to remote is not using SSL.",
   "attr": {
      "connectionId": 69,
      "remote": "10.192.241.225:45516"
   }
}
```

But it is just an information (`"s": "I"`). And yes, the log message "connection to remote..." is a bit misleading. Should be better "connection from remote" or "incoming connection"

Unless you are using [x.509 certificates to authenticate the client](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/), or `net.tls.allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: false` the `net.tls.CAFile` parameter is not needed.

On the other hand, setting `net.tls.CAFile` does not break anything.

Comment: Thanks @Wernfried. I performed the below TLS changes on my cluster and now it looks good. Now, I know these are information logs, because of TLS pattern used in my cluster.

Changes I done in my cluster: No TLS flags in application conf files on mongos servers. TLS.mode=preferTLS in mongos.conf file and TLS.mode=requireTLS on mongod servers.